# Sharing NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey everbody, im trying to share a NSMutableArray to another xib. The cartList.codigo is a NSMutableArray from a shared class, according to James Brannan's tutorial (http://www.vimeo.com/12164589).

When i count it, it gives me 1. But when i load the another view, gives me 0.

Whats wrong?

View that adds:

```
self.produtoCodigo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self.produtoCodigo addObject:@"aa"];

CartViewController *carrinho = [[CartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CartViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

CartList *lista = [[CartList alloc] init];
carrinho.cartList = lista;
carrinho.cartList.codigo = self.produtoCodigo;

NSLog(@"QTD %i", [carrinho.cartList.codigo count]);
```

View that wants to load the item added:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.produtoCodigo = self.cartList.codigo;

NSLog(@"%i", [self.produtoCodigo count]);


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Im loading the CartList class in both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not retaining the array, but only assigning it.

Do you retain the array in the view, something like this -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * produtoCodigo;
```

the "retain" gives your view controller an ownership on the array and you can use it.

Since I don't have your code that is the best I can do to help.

shani

**UPDATE -**

Ok. you do retain it but now i see that the "produtoCodigo" array is retained but you dont pass the array in the view controller.

is seems that you can do 2 things:

1. in your view controller pass the viewController "produtoCodigo" to the view "produtoCodigo".

   ```
     carrinho.produtoCodigo= self.produtoCodigo;
   ```
2. if you already pass the array to the "cartList" then remove the view "produtoCodigo" array, geter and seter (@synthesize & @property). and in the view did load you can:

   ```
     produtoCodigo =[NSMutableArray arraryWithArray: self.cartList.codigo];
   ```

or if you need to use it later you can :

```
     produtoCodigo =[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: self.cartList.codigo];
```

and don't forget to release it later in the second option.

Hope this time it will help

shani

Comment: I'd agree. Whenever you use an Array, make sure you allocate it or retain it in some way. Else you always end up with problems later, and they're a pain to track down.

Comment: Yeah, but i am assigning it. Check it:

Comment: @interface CartViewController : UIViewController {
 
 NSMutableArray *produtoCodigo;
 CartList *cartList;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CartList *cartList;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *produtoCodigo;

Comment: Hi  @Lucas Veiga, i have updated the answer. hope it is all right now.

Comment: When i execute this: self.produtoCodigo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [self.produtoCodigo addObject:@"aa"];
 
 CartViewController *carrinho = [[CartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CartViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 
 carrinho.produtoCodigo = self.produtoCodigo;

 NSLog(@"QTD %i", [carrinho.produtoCodigo count]); It gives me 1. BUt when i enter in CartView it gives 0 yet.